# Need to wipe and reinstall drive. Partition question?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have an older PC (Acer Aspire E1-470P) which i had upgraded through Win10. I decided to try a dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04. I like it, and decided to reapportion my partition to give Ubuntu more space.  I got a USB and put Ubuntu Live on it to boot into to allow me to run gparted. However for some reason my PC wouldn't boot the thumb drive.

At this point I screwed up and I set my boot to "Legacy Boot" and "Secure" (I think), and suddenly I couldn't boot at all.  No operating system found.

I took a chance and installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 18.04 along side my old version. The good news is this succeeded.  I can access files in both my windows partition and in my first Ubuntu position. The bad news is that I can no longer boot into WIn10 (Grub only gives me old and new Ubuntu install boot options), Old Ubuntu won't boot properly (Chain error) , New Ubuntu doesn't like my second monitor even though the first Ubuntu install did (another story, tried nonodeset etc to no avail) and I am stuck in Legacy BIOS boot mode.  I have really messed my partitions and need to reinstall.

I  attached images with partition information, but they aren't showing up so here is a dropbox folder containing the partition details from Ubuntu Disks Utility,  the images can be found

here [url=https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hz0iiwt677rl820/AADbMl1MulaLy30DzFjaEl79a?dl=0]http://[/url]

I would ask for your assistance in which partitions I can / need to recover to get back to a good install. I plan on reinstalling Ubuntu because I like its speed of operation but I would like to retain my Win10 and Old Ubuntu files. If possible, I would like to get back to a world where I could dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu.

Partition 1:  418 MB. Is this my "new ubuntu" boot partition ... (Grub?)
[img]https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9ouaqmdqvq87zj/Part%201.png?dl=0[/img]

Partition 2:  315MB This looks like my EFI partition. Can I get this back?
[img]https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zbdbccwz64yqwj/Part%202.png?dl=0[/img]

Partition 3:  Microsoft reserved but only 134 MB. What is this?
[img]https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhzkux9oa23vru8/Part%203.png?dl=0[/img]

Partition 4:  My old Win10 OS  and files? 300GB 
[img]https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt541d6yoq8pul6/Part%204.png?dl=0[/img]

Partition 6:  BIOS Boot.  Only 1MB. What is this?
[img]https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhwb6bj95ulun87/Part%206.png?dl=0[/img]

Partition 7:  My "new ubuntu" install with 161GB
[img]https://www.dropbox.com/s/lc5ku3pujtbrcth/Part%207.png?dl=0[/img]

Partition 5:  My "Old Ubuntu" install and files 38GB
[img]https://www.dropbox.com/s/up384jn8aidxi3c/Part%205.png?dl=0[/img]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please copy-and-paste properly-formatted text instead of asking folks to wade through seven images full of text. Help us to help you. Looks like you made a lot of classic new-user mistakes, compounded by impatience. Most dual-boot users have 4 partitions: EFI, Win, MS Recovery, and Ubuntu. Anything else is optional. Pro Tip: Fix your monitor problem before mucking with partitions again.

Comment: You have a gpt partitioned drive, so Windows is in UEFI boot mode. If you installed Ubuntu in BIOS/Legacy, then on gpt it has to have a bios_grub partition. Change back to UEFI boot, boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode & run Boot-Repair's full uninstall/reinstall of grub in advanced options. Have you updated UEFI from Acer? Once installed you will need to set "trust". http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Thanks oldfred.  Sorry for all the images.  I thought some of the Ubuntu Disk info might be useful.  Part of the problem is that after I set my boot option to Legacy BIOS and Secure boot, I lost access to my ability to change back to UEFI.   Hitting F2 and F8 (and del and anything else I can think of) doesnt have any effect. It goes right to GRUB and   I can’t get into bios /  boot options.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Oldfred after reviewing your comments   I attempted cold boot.   However even cold, battery removed and replaced it still boots up into grub and no F key or del sends me into boot options.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I couldn't get to the firmware configuration through any key or software.

I wound up opening my laptop, removing HDD and CMOS, "power on" for 20 seconds to drain, replaced old CMOS battery with a new one (hey, it's been five year), booted (Operating System Not Found), powered down, reconnected HDD,rebooted, and voila, I'm back in Win10 with an option to boot Ubuntu from hardware.

Thanks all, esp oldfred, now I will delete partitions 6 and 7 (bios boot and new ubuntu install) and I'll be back to last week.

Now I just need to resize my Ubuntu partition which is where I was when Istarted this mess.  I will research more carefully.

Pallama